# IF function doesn't display df as expected in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, dataframe, jupyter

Rookie question here, I can't understand why this if function isn't returning the previously generated df.

df is 821 rows long, and `print len(output_df.index)>10000` yields `False`.

If statement is the following:

```
if len(output_df.index)>10000:
    print("Table is too large to display, download above")
else:
    HTML(output_df.to_html())
```

I also tried:

```
if len(output_df.index)>10000:
    print("Table is too large to display, download above")
else:
    return HTML(output_df.to_html())
```

and:

```
if len(output_df.index)>10000:
    print("Table is too large to display, download above")
else:
    output_df
```

to no avail. Invoking the table in another cell works just fine. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: In one of the examples you have `return` but not in the others. Is this inside a function? What is `HTML` (in your code)?

Comment: @roganjosh I used return only because I thought it could be the problem. HTML is an imported module from IPython.display. I only used that because else:output_df didn't seem to work. This if statement is not inside a function

Comment: It sounds like the if statement has nothing to do with anything. You can probably edit it out.

Comment: Ok, so in the context of your code, how are you sure that it does nothing? Try adding a `print('Fired!')` inside the `else` case. Do you see anything from that? I'm not familiar with iPython `HTML` but I'm not convinced from these snippets that you should expect some kind of visual output.

Comment: @KennyOstrom not sure what you mean, is there a better way to restrict the df from showing? I'm trying to avoid memory issues by limiting the display based on rows

Comment: @roganjosh tried that and it does print "Fired!"

Comment: In which case your `if`/`else` is working as expected. Your real issue is what you want to do in that particular case, which is not defined in your question.

Comment: @roganjosh understood. I'm trying to display the dataframe, which in my limited experience I normally do by simply writing the name in the cell and running

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the cell". However, in a general case, it's usual just to `print(df.head(however_many_rows_you_want))`. Printing an entire dataframe will not only be slow but probably unintelligible. You need to think of the broader aspect of what you want.

Comment: ok, thanks @roganjosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter only displays the last object.
Try this in one cell:

```
if len(output_df.index)>10000:
    print("Table is too large to display, download above")
    out = None
else:
    out = output_df
out
```

Comment: Aha, so "cell" is the name for individual code blocks `[in]`/`[out]` in Jupyter?